# /etc/shadow date of last password change—UTC or local time?

Tags: password, date, time, timezone

`man 5 shadow` gives the following description of the third field in each line:

> The date of the last password change, expressed as the number of days since Jan 1, 1970.
>
> The value 0 has a special meaning, which is that the user should change her pasword the next time she will log in the system.
>
> An empty field means that password aging features are disabled.

Does this refer to times in UTC or the local timezone? In particular, if I want to calculate comparable numbers using something like `$(( $(date +%s) / 86400 ))`, do I need to pass `date` the `-u` option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "seconds since 1970" timestamp is specifically defined as UTC in most usages. In particular, you may notice that `date +%s` gives the same result as `date -u +%s`.

The relevant line where this is set in the shadow password utilities is"

```
nsp->sp_lstchg = (long) time ((time_t *) 0) / SCALE;
```

Which would make it UTC.
SCALE is defined as 86400 (except via a specific ifdef that I can't quite trace what circumstances cause to be defined)

Answer (score 4):

By "days" it means 86,400 second intervals. By "January 1, 1970", it means 00:00:00 UTC. This is basically standard [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), also known as POSIX time.